# how to upgrade firebase crashlytics in xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, crashlytics

I am trying to upgrade firebase crashlytics SDK, I am trying on MyProject.Android project first.

I have installed [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Firebase.Crashlytics/117.0.0-preview02) NuGet library and all its dependencies. the build is failing with this error on output:

> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.D8.targets(51,5):
> error MSB6006: "java.exe" exited with code

here is the content of that Xamarin.Android.D8.targets file, actually the mentioned 51 line in the error, is the line which start with "<R8" in the image:
[image: here is the content of that Xamarin.Android.D8.targets file, actually the mentioned 51 line in the error, is the line which start with "<R8" in the image:]

I really need help and I do not know what I should to do.

Comment: You need to provide more details, a longer stack trace. And please don’t put code inside screenshots while sharing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, The problem was a conflict between Xamarin.Firebase.Crashlytics and two other libraries, Xamarin..Firebase.Crash and Xamarin.Firebase.Analytics.Impl, it is solved by deleting those both libraries.